# Is it true that $\ln (1+x)$ is smaller than $\sin x$ when $x \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$

Tags: calculus

Is it true that $\ln (1+x)$ is smaller than $\sin x$ when $x \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$ ?

I'm not sure.

I use wolframalpha and find it seems right.

But I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Yes, it is true but if you want a proof of it, you should write in your question what you have tried, otherwise, moderators will close your question and your account too very soon.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2304837/42969, or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1770018/42969, or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1768317/42969 – all found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clog(1%2Bx)%20%5Cle%20%5Csin(x)%24)

Comment: HINT.-It is true as the graphic shows but you have to prove this, for example using the series
$$\sin(x)=x-\dfrac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+\cdots
\\\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\cdots$$